# Printing out the results of a join in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm making a flask app in which every user can add his employees to a list. I have two Tables: User and Employee and they look like this:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    emps = db.relationship('Employee', backref = 'boss', lazy = 'dynamic')


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)


class Employee(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'Employees'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    User_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Employee {0} {1}>'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

I tried adding this to my User class so I can join these two tables:

```
    def user_employees(self):
        user_emps = User.query.join(Employee, User.id == Employee.User_id).filter(User.id == Employee.User_id)
        return user_emps
```

And in my html file I have this:

```
{% block content %}

    {% for employee in employees %}
    <div>{{ employee }}</div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

And this is the view function:

```
def Show_Employees():
    employees = current_user.user_employees()

    return render_template('emps.html', employees = employees)
```

However this doesn't work. I only get this written on my page:

```
<User test
```

The expected output would be first name and last name of the employee.
I guess the problem is with the join but I can't figure it out. Has anyone encountered anything similar?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @Colin employee first name and last name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about joining manually, SQLalchemy takes care of all that for you. You can access the users employees just by `user.emps`, which returns a list of employees. I ditched a lot of your code, which you can add again, just to keep the example small and understandable. It's fully functional:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    emps = db.relationship('Employee', backref = 'boss', lazy = 'dynamic')

class Employee(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Employees'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    User_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))

db.create_all() # creates the database tables, not needed if you already have them

boss1 = User()
boss1.username = 'Mr Boss'
employee1 = Employee()
employee1.first_name =  'Mr peanut'
employee2 = Employee()
employee2.first_name = 'Mr butter'
boss1.emps = [employee1, employee2] # here is where you're binding the employees to the user
db.session.add(boss1)
db.session.commit()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    user = User.query.get(1) # this returns the user with id1, which is 'Mr boss' 
    return render_template_string('''
    This is user {{user.username}}<br>
    His empoyees are:
    {% for employee in user.emps %} 
    <div>{{ employee.first_name }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    ''', user=user)

app.run()
```

Which, if you go to the site, prints:

```
This is user Mr Boss
His empoyees are:
Mr peanut
Mr butter
```

Comment: Very simple solution and it worked great, thank you very much sir!